# Thread exiting when saving some data in shared preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i want to save some data in my shared preference but while saving it is with below exception.
at line **SharedPreferences.Editor store = DefaultData.edit();**

> 05-29 20:20:53.234: E/AndroidRuntime(27650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-29 20:20:53.234: E/AndroidRuntime(27650): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   05-29 20:20:53.234: E/AndroidRuntime(27650):    at com.example.nirbhaya.DefaultDetails.onClick(DefaultDetails.java:92)
>   05-29 20:20:53.234: E/AndroidRuntime(27650):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
>   05-29 20:20:53.234: E/AndroidRuntime(27650):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
>   05-29 20:20:53.234: E/AndroidRuntime(27650):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   05-29 20:20:53.234: E/AndroidRuntime(27650):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   05-29 20:20:53.234: E/AndroidRuntime(27650):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   05-29 20:20:53.234: E/AndroidRuntime(27650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>   05-29 20:20:53.234: E/AndroidRuntime(27650):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-29 20:20:53.234: E/AndroidRuntime(27650):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   05-29 20:20:53.234: E/AndroidRuntime(27650):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   05-29 20:20:53.234: E/AndroidRuntime(27650):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
>   05-29 20:20:53.234: E/AndroidRuntime(27650):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**Java code**
    package com.example.nirbhaya;

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DefaultDetails extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button save,reset;
    EditText dMob,dMsg,dEmail;
    String defMobNo,defMsg,defEmail;
    SharedPreferences DefaultData;

    private static final String TAG = "DD-Activity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.defaultdetails);

        initializing();

    }
    private void initializing() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bsave1);
        reset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bReset);

        dMob = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDefMobNo);
        dMsg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDefMsg);
        dEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDefEmail);

        save.setOnClickListener(this);
        reset.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(arg0.getId())
        {
        case R.id.bsave1:
            defMobNo = dMob.getText().toString();
            defMsg = dMsg.getText().toString();
            defEmail = dEmail.getText().toString();

                Log.i(TAG,"DONE");
                SharedPreferences.Editor store = DefaultData.edit();
                store.putString("defMobileNo", defMobNo);
                store.putString("defMessgae", defMsg);
                store.putString("defEMail", defEmail);
                store.commit();
                Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), CurrentDetails.class);
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);


            break;
        case R.id.bReset:
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDefMobNo)).setText("");
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDefEmail)).setText("");
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDefMsg)).setText("");


            break;
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: added more stacktrace

Answer (score 3):

you missed to initialize `DefaultData`

```
DefaultData = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFS_NAME", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```